# Failed to deploy to azure web app (node application)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure

Hello everyone I'm trying to deploy a node application into azure web app from git repository. but I have this error, thanks in advance.

```
2020-01-16T12:54:36.0206310Z ##[section]Starting: Deploy Azure App Service
2020-01-16T12:54:36.0344775Z ==============================================================================
2020-01-16T12:54:36.0344908Z Task         : Azure App Service deploy
2020-01-16T12:54:36.0345017Z Description  : Deploy to Azure App Service a web, mobile, or API app using Docker, Java, .NET, .NET Core, Node.js, PHP, Python, or Ruby
2020-01-16T12:54:36.0345121Z Version      : 4.160.3
2020-01-16T12:54:36.0345175Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2020-01-16T12:54:36.0345269Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment
2020-01-16T12:54:36.0345352Z ==============================================================================
2020-01-16T12:54:36.8698751Z Got service connection details for Azure App Service:'reactdepnode'
2020-01-16T12:54:37.2965047Z ##[error]Error: Failed to generate web.config. Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\_temp\temp_web_package_3343786491728966\web.config'
2020-01-16T12:54:38.2719194Z Successfully updated deployment History at https://reactdepnode.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/61579179277857
2020-01-16T12:54:38.4948082Z App Service Application URL: http://reactdepnode.azurewebsites.net
2020-01-16T12:54:38.5288754Z ##[section]Finishing: Deploy Azure App Service
```

Comment: Do you get the same exception without using DevOps pipeline? You could test the deployment first by using Local Git, that can be configured from Deployment Center blade of the WebApp. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-local-git